# Name search for special Linear Integer Program

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am looking for a name for the following question in literature!

(and if you know it, then it would be great)

I couldn't find it and due to wide audience here, presumably you know more. Thank you

$$
\text{min}_x \text{max}_k \sum_{i,j}c_{ijk}x_{ij} \quad k = 1 ... d
$$

$$
\sum_{j} x_{ij} = 1  \quad i = 1...n
$$

$$ x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} $$

Comment: you must ask these type of questions in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, what's the question or problem? Is it to compute the min-max subject to the following two constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a robust assignment type of problem. I'm not sure you'll find anything more specific.

Comment: There's a recent survey on assignment problems at https://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDD10/papers_to_read/survey.pdf This includes the remark "Recognizing that there are researchers who have an interest in some variation on the classic AP, but do not know what the standard name of that variation is, thus making it more difficult to search for previous work on the topic, this paper is intended to provide a reasonably comprehensive survey of the different variations on the assignment problem that have appeared in the literature."